# is there anyway to dynamically create an image with embedded hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, hyperlink

i am created images on the fly in my controller (bitmaps, pngs, gif) and sending them down to the view. Is there anyway to embed hyperlinks into an image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Html ImageMaps](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp) is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to embed hyperlinks into images.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just wrap the image with an anchor?

```
<a href="/controller/action/123">
    <img src="/controller/dynamicimage/123" alt="" />
</a>
```

A [html helper method extension](http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/mvc/tutorial-09-cs.aspx) might be useful here to generate previous markup.

Comment: i dont understand this response . . i need links within the image like an image map . .